# Show synced folder when ssh from another PC

Tags: vagrant, synced-folder

When I vagrant up or reload , synced folders are mounted but When I ssh from another pc , synced folders are not showing and when I ssh in the actual machine, synced folders are shown. What am I doing wrong ? Or what do I have to do?

[image: when I vagrant ssh in the actual machine]

[image: when i ssh from another pc]

this is my Vagrant file

```html
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-6.7"
  config.vm.synced_folder "/home/telenet/telenet", "/var/www/html/code",
  :owner => "vagrant",
  :group => "vagrant",
  :mount_options => ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]

  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  #config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "lamp.sh"

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
end

end
```

Answer : In vagrant file , in config.vm.network I add ip: "some ip address" . Then I use that ip address to ssh my virtual box, then boom there it was. It works

Comment: please, describe how exactly do you access to VM from host and from another PC?

Comment: After vagrant up , I do vagrant ssh then go to the file directory for my synced folder , this is how I access the VM from host. And from another PC, I also do ssh using the ip address and username sample : ssh username@ip_address:port_number

@Vadim, Is this what you want to know?

Comment: It will be good if you provide real data. vagrant just setup ordinary VM, if you access by `vagrant ssh` and see data , then no matter which way you access it you should see same data.  Generally if you not see that expect then this means that by mistake you access to some another VM

Comment: @Vadim thank you for that, your comment leads me to the right answer. You are right I have been accessing the wrong VM